# getState of undefined while using customFetchBase to refresh token with rtk query and nestJs

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I receive this error

[image]

I tried to follow the official guide
[officialGuyde](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery)

and this unofficial guide to understanding what to do. I also tried to see several repos, but i wasn't able to find a solution to this.

[unofficialGuide](https://codevoweb.com/react-redux-toolkit-refresh-token-authentication/)

now this is how I set my apiSlice

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import customFetchBase from "./customFetchBase";

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: customFetchBase,
  tagTypes: ["User", "Interests"],
  endpoints: () => ({})
});
```

and this is the relative customFetchBase

```
import {
  BaseQueryFn,
  FetchArgs,
  fetchBaseQuery,
  FetchBaseQueryError
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";
import { Mutex } from "async-mutex";

const baseUrl = `${process.env.BASE_URL}`;

// Create a new mutex
const mutex = new Mutex();

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl
});

const customFetchBase: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  // wait until the mutex is available without locking it
  await mutex.waitForUnlock();
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
  console.log("-> result", result);
  if ((result.error?.data as any)?.message === "You are not logged in") {
    if (!mutex.isLocked()) {
      const release = await mutex.acquire();
      console.log("-> release", release);

      try {
        const refreshResult = await baseQuery(
          { credentials: "include", url: "oauth/token" },
          api,
          extraOptions
        );
        console.log("-> refreshResult", refreshResult);

        if (refreshResult.data) {
          // Retry the initial query
          result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
        }
        /* else {
          api.dispatch(logout());
          window.location.href = "/login";
        } */
      } finally {
        // release must be called once the mutex should be released again.
        release();
      }
    } else {
      // wait until the mutex is available without locking it
      await mutex.waitForUnlock();
      result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
    }
  }

  return result;
};

export default customFetchBase;
```

if i try to change

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL }) /// ----> different line from the previous code snippet
  tagTypes: ["User", "Interests"],
  endpoints: () => ({})
});
```

everything works fine. I tried to see several repos, but i didn't find anything that could help to understand what's going on, or what to do to debug. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Look at the callstack in the error, it looks like an issue accessing the `store` object in the `Provider` component from `react-redux`. You will probably want to start your investigation there.

Comment: Thank you Drew! i will post more details about how i use them asap :), in the meanwhile, really appreciate your comment!