# Nextjs implementing Mutex on Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux, mutex, redux-toolkit

So, i have a store

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({}).concat([api.middleware]),
});
```

an api thing from @reduxjs/toolkit/query/react

```
export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: baseQuery,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({})
})
```

Then if i insert

```
import { Mutex } from 'async-mutex'; <<--

const mutex = new Mutex(); <<--

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: BASE_API_V1,
});

export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: baseQuery,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({})
})
```

Always getting

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')`

Already put my store in my app class

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

What thing that i miss?

If i remove that `const mutex = new Mutex();`

Everything is working fine.

But i need to use that, since i want to implement the `baseQueryWithReauth` thing.

[Same problem but not solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75251932/getstate-of-undefined-while-using-customfetchbase-to-refresh-token-with-rtk-quer)

I already read it, but still not find anything that help me.
Since my reputation still not enough for commenting, so i make new question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem and after reading the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/DirtyHairy/async-mutex)
they mentioned:

> Starting with Node 12.16 and 13.7, native ES6 style imports are supported.

> WARNING: Node 13 versions < 13.2.0 fail to import this package correctly. Node 12 and earlier are fine, as are newer versions of Node 13.

you might want to check your node version with `node --version`